# Typoscript : Separate Content Header from Body Text

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

YES, I have been looking for answers and couldn't find anything that worked or did what I wanted it to do. Neither in German nor in English, so this is my last resort:

I included a Javascript on the site I am programming. The usual JQuery Content Slider.
(    http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/toggleElements/ ).
I included it into a Typo3 Site. I created a stdWrap so that each entry in the column "Normal" ends up in one of the sliders. All very nice so far.
The Documentation says it uses:

```
 <div class="toggler-c" title="Example 1">
```

to declare each toggler.
My wrap looks like this:

```
10.marks.CONTENT = COA
  10.marks.CONTENT.10 = CONTENT
  10.marks.CONTENT.10 {
    renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="toggler-c" title="" >|</div>
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos = 0
    }
```

The Problem is that this will write everything including the header of the entry into the toggler and doesnt use the header as the visible title.
I dont know how to grab the Header of the content element to write it into the "title"-attibute of the wrap.

Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Halest

EDIT:

I have been trying different things: 
How far is this off?

```
  10.marks.CONTENT = COA
  10.marks.CONTENT.10 = CONTENT
  10.marks.CONTENT.10 {

    renderObj < tt_content
    renderObj.stdWrap.cObject {
      key = CType
      header = |
      default = <div class="toggler-c" title="|" ></div>
      bodytext = |
      default = <div class="toggler-c" title="">|</div>
    }

    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos = 0
    }
```

(This doesnt show anything but I wonder if it is THAT wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I got it to work, thanks anyway I guess?!

```
10.marks.CONTENT = COA
  10.marks.CONTENT.10 = CONTENT
  10.marks.CONTENT.10 {


table = tt_content
select.orderBy = sorting
select.where = colPos = 0



renderObj < tt_content
   renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
     10 = TEXT
     10.field = header
     10.wrap = title="|"
     20 = TEXT
     20.field = bodytext
     20.wrap = >|
     wrap =  <div class="toggler-c" |</div>
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well, you could have just changed the bodytext wrap inside tt_content instead of rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: What do you mean, where and how?

Comment: Have a look at the `TSOB` at the branch `tt_content`.

Answer (score 1):

My version according to the above posts and some searching on the web:

I've put this in the marks part of the template:

```
HEADING = CONTENT
HEADING{
    # find current content from the tt_content table
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos = 0

    # render the header as simple text
    renderObj < tt_content
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.field = header
}


CONTENT = CONTENT
CONTENT{
    # same goes here
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos = 0

    # trying to render the bodytext as an HTML content
    renderObj < tt_content
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.field = bodytext
    renderObj.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE   # Remove this line, if you want to remove the <p class="bodytext"> markups
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You properly want to have a look at the `tt_content` part in the TypoScript Object Browser.

What you needs is as `CASE` with `key = CType` and a special configuration for header (empty wrap) and default with your wrap for all other elements.

```
renderObj.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
renderObj.stdWrap.cObject {
  key = CType
  header = |
  default = <div class="toggler-c" title="" >|</div>
}
```

(Untested).

Comment: Does noone have another idea? anyone?